# Decode ASN.1 data from CAC/x509 certificate extension (Subject Directory Attributes > Country of Citizenship)

Tags: c#, asp.net, x509, asn.1, x509certificate2

I need to read a x509 property not published via the X509Certificate2 class. Therefor I need to read it's OID and decoded the ASN.1 data myself.

Specifically, I need to read "Subject Directory Attributes" > "Country of Citizenship" OID 2.5.29.9 and 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.9.4 respectively. Keep in mind Subject Directory Attributes is a collection and I'm only truly after Citizenship.

Right now i can obtain the ASN.1 data and can run it through 
[this javascript decoder](http://lapo.it/asn1js/#3012301006082B06010505070904310413025553) and see OID (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.9.4) and the value I'm after (US) but I can't figure out how to decode the data in C# and further more target the Citizenship OID. Here is the following code I have so far:

```
var citizenship = (
    from X509Extension ext in x509.Extensions
    where ext.Oid.Value == "2.5.29.9"
    select new AsnEncodedData(ext.Oid, ext.RawData).Format(true)
);
```

And the RawData in hex is "30 12 30 10 06 08 2b 06 01 05 05 07 09 04 31 04 13 02 55 53"

[EDIT] I am looking to read this value within a webpage and serializing to disk doesn't really suite my needs here.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks for being a prick and downvoting/editing my posts going back over 4 years. Shows your truly trying to help the community.Edit this one too.

Comment: Editing is normal on this site. If you don't like your posts to be edited,  you're on the wrong site. Which downvote did you have an issue with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Asn1Net.Reader](https://github.com/peponeska/Asn1Net.Reader). When you open the "RawData" (but saved as binary to a file) in [ASN.1 editor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4910/ASN-Editor) or [Asn1Viewer](https://github.com/peponeska/Asn1Net.Forms.Viewer) you can see the structure of the ASN.1 data. Below is the picture taken from ASN.1 editor.

[image: Structure of you citizenship ASN.1 object]

Then with Asn1Net.Reader (nuget [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Asn1Net.Reader/)) you can parse the value with this code (no not null checking has been done; and I am using nunit test here)

```
[Test]
[TestCase("30 12 30 10 06 08 2B 06 01 05 05 07 09 04 31 04 13 02 55 53")]
public void ReadCitizenship(string example)
{
    // translates hex to byte[]
    var encoded = Helpers.GetExampleBytes(example);

    // initialize reader
    var reader = Helpers.ReaderFromData(encoded);

    // parse ASN.1 object to the end and read value as byte[]
    var subjDirAttributes = reader.ReadToEnd(true);

    // NO Checking for null has been done
    //                                  sequence      sequence      set           printable string
    var citizenship = subjDirAttributes.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[0];

    var value = citizenship.ReadContentAsPrintableString();
    Assert.IsTrue(value == "US");
}
```

You can parse any ASN.1 object with this reader and if you know the structure you can read any value out of it.

**UPDATE:**
According to [RFC 3739](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3739#section-3.2.2) Subject Directory Attributes is defined in [section 3.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3739#section-3.2.2). There is an example in [appendix C.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3739#appendix-C.3). Subject directory attributes of given certificates are shown below.

[image: Subject directory attributes example from RFC 3739]

According to the structure defined in RFC 3739 this code should parse out all citizenship values.

```
[Test]
public void ReadCitizenship()
{
    var exampleCert = @"MIIDEDCCAnmgAwIBAgIESZYC0jANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBIMQswCQYDVQQGEwJE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";

    var cer = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(exampleCert));
    var ext = cer.Extensions.OfType<X509Extension>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Oid.Value == "2.5.29.9");

    var citizenshipValues = new List<string>();

    // initialize reader
    var reader = Helpers.ReaderFromData(ext.RawData);

    // parse ASN.1 object to the end and read value as byte[]
    var subjDirAttributes = reader.ReadToEnd(true);


    var citizenshipAsn1Object = subjDirAttributes.ChildNodes[0];

    foreach (var node in citizenshipAsn1Object.ChildNodes)
    {
        var shouldBeOidNode = node.ChildNodes[0];

        if (shouldBeOidNode.Identifier.Tag != Asn1Type.ObjectIdentifier) // should be oid
            throw new FormatException("Invalid structure of Subject Directory Attributes");

        var oidValue = shouldBeOidNode.ReadContentAsObjectIdentifier();

        if (oidValue != "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.9.4")
            continue;

        // found it
        
        var setNode = node.ChildNodes[1];
        if (setNode.Identifier.Tag != Asn1Type.Set)
            throw new FormatException("Invalid structure of Subject Directory Attributes");

        foreach (var internalNode in setNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            var valueOfCitizenship = internalNode.ReadContentAsPrintableString();
            if (valueOfCitizenship.Length != 2)
                throw new FormatException("Invalid value in countryOfCitizenship. Length should be exactly 2 characters.");

            citizenshipValues.Add(valueOfCitizenship);
        }

        // found all values, lets break
        break;
    }

    Assert.IsTrue(citizenshipValues.Count == 1);
}
```

Comment: pepo, this would only hold true if the first attribute in the "Subject Directory Attributes" was the OID (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.9.4) I was looking for was in fact the first, correct?

Comment: The RawData that you gave as an example held only the OID and the value US as shown on the picture. Therefore my answer was based on this value.

Comment: @m4chine OK, here you go. Based on RFC specification. See updated answer.

Comment: I installed Asn1Net.Reader 1.0.0.1 but the Helpers class doesn't have a method ReaderFromData(). I inspected the assembly/class and its not there. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @m4chine sorry, it's class from my unit test project. You can find source code [here](https://github.com/peponeska/Asn1Net.Reader/blob/master/src/Asn1Net.Reader/Tests/BerReaderTests/Helpers.cs#L29)

Comment: no worries. Another couple questions, I see the github has code not yet published to nuget. Do plan on updating nuget anytime soon? Eg InternalNode.ReadContentAsPrintableString and the biggest one, for me is that the assembly doesn't have a strong name, not signed. The project I'm working with requires strong names. If not I can download the repository myself. Thanks agian.

Comment: @m4chine I'm planing to make a new nuget in a couple of days. I didn't plan to strongly name the assembly but I see no reason to not sign it, It would have to be a separate nuget package. I will think about it.

Comment: @m4chine I have made a new version. It's also on nuget. I will not make a strong name version for now.

Answer (score 0):

I have cteated custom universal function for parsing certificate subject atributes. It will help you!

1) cteate custom model

```
    public class ModelCertParams
    {
        public string CN;
        public string S;
        public string E;
        public string L;
        public string O;
        public string C;
        public string STREET;
        public string OU;
        public string TIN = String.Empty;
        public string PINFL = String.Empty;
}
```

2) Parse subject value from certificate

```
 X509Certificate2 myCert = new X509Certificate2(cert, "pkcs12password");

String issureName = myCert.GetIssuerName().ToString();
String ClientName = myCert.Subject;

ModelCertParams IssureModel = getExtentionSubject(issureName);
ModelCertParams CertParams = getExtentionSubject(ClientName);
```

3) Create function getExtentionSubject()

```
 public static ModelCertParams getExtentionSubject(String data)
        {
            ModelCertParams mcert = new ModelCertParams();
            mcert.C = ExtParse(data, "C");
            mcert.CN = ExtParse(data, "CN");
            mcert.O = ExtParse(data, "O");
            mcert.OU = ExtParse(data, "OU");
            mcert.L = ExtParse(data, "L");
            mcert.S = ExtParse(data, "S");
            mcert.TIN = ExtParse(data, "TIN") == "" ? ExtParse(data, "OID.1.2.860.3.16.1.1") : "";
            mcert.PINFL = ExtParse(data, "PINFL") == "" ? ExtParse(data, "OID.1.2.860.3.16.1.2") : "";
            mcert.E = ExtParse(data, "E");
            mcert.STREET = ExtParse(data, "STREET");

            return mcert;
        }
```

4) create parser function

```
 public static string ExtParse(string data, string delimiter)
        {

            string result = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                if (data == null || data == "") return result;

                if (!delimiter.EndsWith("=")) delimiter = delimiter + "=";

                //data = data.ToUpper(); // if you need
                if (!data.Contains(delimiter)) return result;

                int start = data.IndexOf(delimiter) + delimiter.Length;

                string e = data.Substring(start, data.IndexOf('=', start) == -1 ? data.Length - start : data.IndexOf('=', start) - start);
                int tt = e.Length - e.LastIndexOf(", ");

                int length = data.IndexOf('=', start) == -1 ? data.Length - start : data.IndexOf('=', start) - start - tt;

                if (length == 0) return result; 
                if (length > 0)
                {
                    result = data.Substring(start, length);

                }
                else
                {
                    result = data.Substring(start);
                }
                return result;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
```